# How can I stop Google Sheets formatting a Forms response as a date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, formatting

I have a Google Forms with a question that contains a drop-down box with the following values:

```
 - Fewer than 10
 - 11-25
 - 26-50
 - More than 50
```

If the user selects `11-25`, Google Sheets renders the response data like this: [image: ono halp]

Under the formats dropdown in the toolbar, selecting "Plain Text" has the cell render as this date. Selecting "Normal" gives just `40,872`, and selecting any other type of format gives `$ 40,872.00`, `980928:00:00`, and other various numbers that aren't anything like `11-25`, depending on what option I choose.

The workaround is to change the Forms response option to `11-25 apples`, or to recognize when manipulating my data that '11/25/2011' really means '11-25 apples'.

But is there a way to get Google Sheets to stop turning `11-25` into a date?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to format the column in spreadsheet mode *before* any data is entered.

Here we have a form about waffles. The cells have been formatted before sending it to the recipients.

[image: How many waffles would you like]

And here is the result after a user fills out the result.

[image: A lot of waffles]

Comment: Aha. Shame there's no way to fix it after the fact, but, now I know! Thanks.

Comment: This makes me wish Google would go out of business tomorrow. I now and forever hate Google, with a passion. This is the worst thing ever. I hate Google for this, DAMN YOU GOOGLE!

Comment: @WraithKenny fight the power, Kenny.

Comment: If you do Text to Columns conversion, then this won't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can also put 3 - 5 instead of 3-5. It worked for me.

Comment: That's a good workaround for people like me who forget to format the columns ahead of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@Brandon](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/24881/brandon)'s A, use `11—25` (em dash as separator) rather than `11-25` (hyphen/minus as separator)