# Persistent column formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Sheet with an input form.  I click the top of a column to highlight the entire column and set format to Currency with two decimal places.  This puts the dollar sign in front of all the previous currency values.  But when I add new lines to the sheet via the form, the new cells do not show the dollar sign.  Is this just a limitation of the Sheets platform, or can I persistently set the Currency format on a column?

Comment: There's an answer on that question that seems to be applicable to your situation.  If for some reason that answer doesn't work for you, please edit this question to indicate why and it will be queued to be reopened.  Thanks!

Comment: I read all the answers to the other question, and I got lost.  I don't see that other question as an exact duplicate, though they both may have the ultimate answer "can't do it".  Are you suggesting there is some leading [ in the input that will recognize the column formatting?

Comment: I don't think they're duplicates either. Closely related, sure. Unfortunately, I don't know if there's a viable solution in either case.

Comment: My apologies, Lester, I should have linked to the answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66266 was the one I was looking at, in terms of taking the entries into a different sheet.  The fact that the answer was leaning toward there not being a solution was the deciding factor.  I really have no problem with re-opening, though, honestly.

Comment: Not sure that StackExchange Q&A map well to something like Sheets, which probably has a private specification document hundreds of pages long, and that has changed with various releases.  There may be hundreds of queries that can only be answered with a shrug, or "probably not".