# How to deactivate auto-formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I was trying to type things in Google Sheets, but I can't find a way for the app not to automatically change some of the things I type.

For example I can enter (-3000) in a cell and nothing happens, but when I try to type (2000), as soon as I click away from the cell, the parentheses are gone. Same thing if I try to type " ' " on its own, it disappears and the cell looks empty, or if it's the first character, let's say I try to type " 'an ", it will render " an ".

Does anyone know why it does that and how to deactivate it, or at least reverse it cell by cell.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. It's worthy to note that this behavior is the same in other spreadsheet apps like Microsoft Excel.

Cell starting with a `=` or `+` are interpreted as formulas. Values starting with `'` are interpreted as text values. The default value "conversion" / "formatting" might vary based on the spreadsheet regional setting but the use `=`, `+` and `'` are the same for all the regional settings. Considering this,

- If you want to display a `'` enter `''`
- If you want to display `(2000)` you could apply a custom number format or enter `'(2000)`

Related

- [How can I stop Google Sheets formatting a Forms response as a date?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18169/88163)
- [Stop Google Sheets formatting text as URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122036/88163)